# Spring Boot transitive @Component dependencies with @ConditionalOnBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a `Spring Boot 1.5.x` project where some `@Component` depends on other `@Component`, and ultimately along the chain of dependencies, some `@Component` can be enabled or disabled completely using `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

I am using `@ConditionalOnBean` to avoid instantiating `@Component` that depends on other `@Component` that have not been instantiated because of missing `properties`.

**However, it works only for direct dependencies, and not for transitive dependencies, but I can't understand why.**

Let me try to explain with a simple example.

Considering `MyServices.kt`:

```
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

class MyServices

@ConditionalOnProperty("service.a")
@Service
class ServiceA {
    init {
        logger.info { "A SERVICE" }
    }
}

@ConditionalOnBean(ServiceA::class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("service.b")
@Service
class ServiceB(
        private val serviceA: ServiceA
) {
    init {
        logger.info { "B SERVICE depends on $serviceA" }
    }
}

@ConditionalOnBean(ServiceB::class)
@ConditionalOnProperty("service.c")
@Service
class ServiceC(
        private val serviceB: ServiceB
) {
    init {
        logger.info { "C Service depends on $serviceB" }
    }
}
```

With the following `application.yml`:

```
service:
  a: false
  b: true
  c: true
```

then Spring crashes at startup with the following:

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.ServiceC required a bean of type 'org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.ServiceB' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.ServiceB' in your configuration.
```

Here is the result of the autoconfiguration:

```
Positive matches:

ServiceC matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (service.c) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.ServiceB; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'serviceB' (OnBeanCondition)

Negative matches:

ServiceA:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (service.a) found different value in property 'service.a' (OnPropertyCondition)

   ServiceB:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.ServiceA; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (service.b) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

---

However, with the following `application.yml`:

```
service:
  a: true
  b: false
  c: true
```

then everything works fine, only an instance of `ServiceA` gets instantiated, while no `ServiceB` nor `ServiceC` beans are created.

---

The same kind of behavior with `@Bean` instead of `@Component` works as expected.

`MyBeans.kt`:

```
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

@Configuration
class MyBeans {

    @ConditionalOnProperty("bean.a")
    @Bean
    fun beanA(): BeanA {
        logger.info { "A BEAN" }
        return BeanA("beanA")
    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(BeanA::class)
    @ConditionalOnProperty("bean.b")
    @Bean
    fun beanB(beanA: BeanA): BeanB {
        logger.info { "B BEAN depends on $beanA" }
        return BeanB("beanB")
    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(BeanB::class)
    @ConditionalOnProperty("bean.c")
    @Bean
    fun beanC(beanB: BeanB): BeanC {
        logger.info { "C BEAN depends on $beanB" }
        return BeanC("beanC")
    }

}

data class BeanA(val name: String)
data class BeanB(val name: String)
data class BeanC(val name: String)
```

With `application.yml`:

```
bean:
  a: false
  b: true
  c: true
```

I get no beans of type `BeanA`, `BeanB`, or `BeanC` instantiated.

Here is the result of the autoconfiguration:

```
Negative matches:

MyBeans#beanA:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (bean.a) found different value in property 'bean.a' (OnPropertyCondition)

   MyBeans#beanB:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.BeanA; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (bean.b) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   MyBeans#beanC:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.gotson.transitivebeandependencies.BeanB; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (bean.c) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

---

I have setup a sample repo with tests to reproduce: https://github.com/gotson/spring-transitive

Comment: Interesting one,  first diff i can see for service is `ConditionalOnProperty`is evaluated  at `PARSE_CONFIGURATION`  phase, and `ConditionalOnBean` at `REGISTER_BEAN`.
ServiceA having only onProperty it's well not register, but ServiceB have both, and Spring, while looking for candidate to register only check `PARSE_CONFIGURATION`, this lead to `serviceB` registered in beanFactory, and the onBeanCondition check in beanFactory for an existing potential bean matching, before really create them.

Comment: I have added details of the autoconfiguration report. It's weird that ServiceC is a match on `@ConditionalOnBean` while ServiceB isn't though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@ConditionalOnBean` is a bean registration phase check and, as such, needs to have an overview of what beans are effectivly available in the `ApplicationContext`. Beans can be registered in a standard fashion with a regular `@Bean`, exposing the same target type as the return type of the method. You may also have `FactoryBean` with a more complex logic that can lead to exotic setup we have to handle.

Regardless, ordering is key. Configuration classes have to be processed in a given order if you want bean type matching to work properly. If you have a `C1` configuration class that contributes a bean `A` only if bean `B` is available and said bean is contributed by `C2`, `C2` *has to run first*.

Spring Boot has a two steps parsing phase: first we parse all the user's configuration. Once that's done, we parse the bean definitions of auto-configurations. Auto-configurations themselves are ordered (using `@AutoConfigureBefore`, `@AutoConfigureAfter`). That way, we can guarantee that if you put `@ConditionalOnBean` in an auto-configuration, it will be processed as expected with regards to user configuration. And if you rely on something contributed by another auto-configuration, you can easily order it using those annotations.

Your setup completely eludes ordering so it works if the ordering is right and doesn't if it isn't. The Javadoc of `@ConditionalOnBean` clearly [states that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html)

> it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only.

If you want to know more, there is a 3h university session available that covers, namely, this very topic [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uof5h-j0IeE).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, i'll watch the video when i can. Back to my problem, is there also some relation to the fact that `@Component` does not have the same lifecycle as `@Bean` ? My understanding would be that even if the ordering was correct, beans generated by `@Component` annotation are added to the bean factory during the component scan?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It works with `@Bean` because everything is in the same class and therefore there is no order problem since you have one source (the `MyBeans` `@Configuration` class). That's pretty much what I've tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: Actually i'm more trying to understand why it's not working with `@Component`. I put the `@Bean` example to draw a parallel.

Comment: My answer explains why it doesn't work with `@Component` (order is different so by the time we check if the bean is there, it is not there so the condition fail and the bean is then created _after_). I don't really know what part of it isn't clear.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, it's clearer now. I'll fall back to using properties to enable/disable some behaviors instead then, it's a bit more work but at least it works reliably.

Comment: That doesn't sound right at all and something I wouldn't do. It can be reliable if you use the tools as intended. Backing off in case a user has defined a bean requires auto-configuration. And creating one isn't hard at all so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: My app has some infrastructure beans that are configured using `@Conditional`, those works fine, and indeed i could migrate them to use proper autoconfiguration, but so far they work great without specific autoconfiguration. I also have business beans, which depend on infrastructure beans, that's where i tried to use transitive `@Conditional`, but it didn't work. Basically what i am trying to achieve is to create or not the business beans depending on the configuration keys that pilot the infra beans.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is your definition of controls.

For the @Service example (false,true,true), your control property determines whether the Service is Defined.  ServiceA is not defined nor constructed. ServiceB is defined, but not constructed because there is no ServiceA definition. ServiceC is defined and construction is attempted.  As indicated, the construction of ServiceC fails due to the absence of an instance of ServiceB.

For the @Bean example (false,true,true), your control property determines whether the Bean is constructed.  BeanA is not constructed, BeanB is not constructed because there is no BeanA, and BeanC is not constructed because there is no BeanB.

For the @Service example (true,false,true):
ServiceA is defined and constructed, ServiceB is neither defined nor constructed, ServiceC is defined but no construction is attempted because ServiceB is not defined.

Methods decorated with @Bean produce a bean to be managed by the Spring container during configuration stage.

A Java class decorated with @Component (@Service) will be detected during component scan process and registered as a Spring bean.

Because the @Service annotation does not create and register the component in the same way that @Bean does, it is possible that using [@ConditionalOnClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) instead of @ConditionalOnBean may produce the results you want.  There are some caveats regarding this annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't tell me why the above doesn't work, and how it could work?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is unclear... In regard to the "how it could work?" question, I have added a paragraph.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnClass` is looking at the classpath, since the jar layout will not change, it will not work (i just tested it). I think all in all it may boil down to the difference between a proper Bean registered with `@Bean` and an implicit Bean created by Spring via `@Component`, however i fail to see why my examples couldn't work given those concepts.